# Post petition with angular2

Tags: angular

I try to create a user registration with angular2 and I don't understand why is the problem.

The error that launch angular2 is the following error.

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

So I have the following code

In component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User} from '../../usuarios/signup/user';
import { Router , ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SignUpService } from '../../usuarios/signup/signup.service';     
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})    
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario: User = new User()

  constructor(private signUpService:SignUpService,private router:Router , private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  userRegistration(): void {
    this.signUpService.userRegistration(this.usuario);
  }

}
```

And service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../usuarios/signup/user';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class SignUpService {

        private urlEndpoint:string = 'http://localhost:8584/api/public/v1/countries';

        private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({'Content-type':'application/json'});

        constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

        userRegistration(user:User){
          this.http.post(this.urlEndpoint,user,{headers:this.httpHeaders});
        }

    }
```

User model

Now , this petition is working with Postman.

Comment: What is the exact and complete error? Which function does it complain about? Note that setting the Content-Type header is completely unnecessary, and that your userRegistration method is useless, since it creates an observable to which nothing can subscribe, since it doesn't return it. So nothing will ever happen if you call that method. You're also using old imports for rxjs. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Your `userRegistration(user:User)` should be returning that observable, if you plan to subscribe to it on your `SignUpComponent` component